# Fusion of two queries in active record rails

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

How could these two queries be merged in Rails 5?

```
Event
.where(starts_at: date.beginning_of_day..date.end_of_day)
.where(kind: "opening")

Event.where("cast(strftime('%w', starts_at) as int) = ?", date.wday)
.where(kind: "opening")
.where(weekly_recurring: true)
```

I need to take all these events in one query for performance.

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

If you want to combine results then

```
Event.where(starts_at: date.beginning_of_day..date.end_of_day).where(kind: "opening").where("cast(strftime('%w', starts_at) as int) = ?", date.wday).where(kind: "opening").where(weekly_recurring: true)
```

If you want two separate results in one query, i dont think active records has such method.

Comment: This is not what i need :( i need opening event with good begining_of_day and end_of_day AND event with good day (cast(strftime....).

Answer (score 0):

I have always easier to write complex queries such as the one you need directly in SQL; It will be faster for you to write than trying to shoehorn it into ActiveRecord.

In your case, I would do something like this:

```
query = "starts_at between #{date.beginning_of_day} and #{date.end_of_day} 
and kind = 'opening'
and weekly_recurring = true
and cast(strftime('%w', starts_at) as int) = #{date.wday}"

Event.where(query)
```

I find this approach easier and more maintanable.